# HBO and TED talks video maximizes on wrong monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, video, hdmi

I want to stream videos from my laptop to my TV through an HDMI cable that I have bought.  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

While I have been able to do this for YouTube videos, I haven't for others like HBO and TED talks.  The reason is that when I maximize it to full screen, the video gets maximized on my laptop monitor.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Notice that what I mean with maximization is not about the window, but about the video which I want to watch.
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Which screen is the browser on when you switch the video embedded within it, to full screen?

Comment: @dobey The browser is on the screen which I want it to be maximized on.  YouTube does maximize it on the right screen but not the other videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to modify the layout of the screens and put the TV on the left of the laptop LCD.

To do that go to Settings > Displays

Then drag the TV to the left of the laptop LCD.

If that does not work you could choose to turn off the laptop LCD and have only the TV on.

Comment: Great, this is a simple solution and it did the job.

Comment: Diego - if this worked you should mark the answer accepted -- it lets other people know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible solution for full screening flash in Firefox is the add-on called [Flash Game Maximiser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-game-maximizer/). Once installed you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> after clicking on any flash program (game or video) to make it fill the current window. Then you can use <kbd>F11</kbd> like normal to make that Firefox window fill the screen.

Comment: While this add-on should do what I am looking for, it didn't worked well for me when I installed it.


I thought to mention it in case other people find the same behaviour.

Comment: That's interesting. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: The video doesn't adjust its size to the window.  That is, the window blacks out outside of the video, but the video keeps its original size.

Comment: :( normally works for me, not tryed on TED and I don't have HBO. Pity